# Is there a way to add "Album" to the stream title of an Icecast2 server?

Tags: icecast

I currently have a radio player that streams audio from an Icecast server. The player includes the current song metadata from the Icecast admin, but I also need to include album in the metadata. Is there any way this is possible using just the Icecast server?

Answer (score 1):

This will depend on the format you are streaming in.

If you are streaming Ogg encapsulated audio, including Opus, then the whole metadata is available to you in the stream. It is entirely up to the individual player software to display it in a sensible way.
In case of Firefox there is a experimental metadata API in Javascript that provides information about a HTML5 <audio> element.

If you are streaming one of the other formats, like MP3 or AAC, then there is really only one metadata field. You can put anything you want there. Players might interpret it in certain ways though, like splitting it at a "-" into Artist and Title fields. Nothing of this is really well defined as it originates from the hacks introduced by Shoutcast. Inside icecast it's handled as a single field.

Comment: Where do I make changes to the one metadata field for the MP3/AAC formats?

Comment: http://icecast.org/docs/icecast-2.4.1/admin-interface.html#metadata-update - covers this topic